# ClassNotFoundException oracle.disco.DiscoApplet error using Oracle BI Discoverer

Tags: java, oracle

I´m trying to connect to Oracle BI Discoverer, but when i will connect after select the responsability the website keeps in white and an error appears: 
ClassNotFoundException
oracle.disco.DiscoApplet

**Java console shows:
Java Plug-in 10.45.2.18
Using JRE version 1.7.0_45-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\druizran**

---

### c:   clear console window f:   finalize objects on finalization queue g:   garbage collect h:   display this help message l:   dump classloader list m:   print memory usage o:   trigger logging q:   hide console r:   reload policy configuration s:   dump system and deployment properties t:   dump thread list v:   dump thread stack x:   clear classloader cache 0-5: set trace level to

What´s happening?

Comment: Does this typically work or are you trying to configure this for the first time?

Comment: It´s the first time.

Comment: Is Disco Viewer configured and working (e.g. the server appears to be configured sufficiently enough for Viewer to work)? Have you configured the server to be compatible with Java 7 (there are patches)?

Comment: I don't have access to the server. I'm only client.

Comment: Can you start a Disco Viewer session (does not need Java jre on client)?

Comment: Not until tomorrow.